# Is there a way to prevent jQuery from .submit if the viewport width is less than X?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a jQuery like this which automatically submits when a form value is changed:

```
$( "#results" ).change(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
    $.blockUI({ 
        message: $('#filters'),
    });
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

I'd like to prevent this from happening however on mobile devices, to give users a chance to select several options at once and then manually submit. Is this possible? I'm thinking something with `var w = e.target.innerWidth;` and `w > 1 && w < 992` for example but I can't quite figure out where to put it.

Comment: You can use $(window).width() to identify the screen size and add a validation like this action should only be fired from specific screen size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about putting the submit-call in an if-block testing the variables you mentioned? And then providing a normal submit-button, which you can hide for bigger screens using css.

```js
$( "#results" ).change(function() {
  var w = e.target.innerWidth;
    if(w > 1 && w < 992){
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }
    $.blockUI({ 
        message: $('#filters'),
    });
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

I think you were just thinking to complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(window.innerWidth < x) || $(this).closest("form").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$( "#results" ).change(function(e) {
var w = e.target.innerWidth;
var mobile_width= 450;
     if(w > mobile_width){
           $(this).closest("form").submit();
           $.blockUI({ 
               message: $('#filters'),
           });
           $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
     }
});
```